# How to add the clients into a SUB DOMAIN DNS Linux

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, subdomain

DNS Master is dns1.example.com
DNS Master Forward zone is example.com.forward.zone

SUB Domain named is suba1 & suba2
SUB Domain Forward zone is suba1.example.com.forward.zone

Host Client which will connect to these Sub Domains are :

```
host01
host02
```

Do i need to Create the `A` & `PTR` record in both the zone files including **example.com.forward.zone** and **suba1.example.com.forward.zone**  for the host01 & host02 ?

Below are my example domain forward zone and subdomain suba1.example.com zone files..

```
[root@dns1 ~]# cat example.com.forward.zone
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  example.com.            root.example.com. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@               NS      dns1.example.com.
                A       127.0.0.1
host01          A       192.168.11.2
host02          A       192.168.11.3
suba1           NS      dns1.example.com.
suba2           NS      dns1.example.com.


[root@dns1 ~]# cat  suba1.example.com.forward.zone
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  tony.example.com.               root.example.com. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@               NS      dns1.example.com.
                A       127.0.0.1

; this is entry for www.suba1.example.com
www             A       192.168.1.11
```

Comment: Try it.  Put the hosts in one of the sub zones.  Flush cache and update the servers.  Try to resolve from the parent zone using fqdn (e.g. host01.suba1.example.com) and see if it works.  I'm not an expert for DNS forwarding, but what you've posted there looks like the hosts are in the parent domain.

Comment: `PTR` records are seldom needed (for emails mostly) so you can skip them on first try (and you need to remember that to be able to use them you will need to have delegation from your ISP to manage the reverse zone, it is completely separate from the (forward) name based zone). As for `A` records (or `AAAA` you need some if the host needs to be reachable in some way...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thnx for the inputs it helps.